# tomcat conf/context.xml - Property 'factory' not supported

Tags: tomee-7

I'm trying to change the connection pool of my web app to use the Tomcat Connection pool (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory).  So, I added the factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" line into the conf/context.xml file, like below:

```
<Context>
   <Resource 
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
   name="jdbc/mcbell" 
   auth="Application" 
   maxActive="50" 
   maxIdle="30" 
   maxWait="10000" 
   removeAbandoned="true" 
   removeAbandonedTimeout="1200" 
   logAbandoned="true"
   driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
   url="jdbc:as400://mcbell4;secure=true;naming=system;errors=full;prompt=false;libraries=*LIBL;timeFormat=iso;dateFormat=iso;dateSeparator=-"
   username="" 
   password=""
   validationQuery="select 1 from sysibm/sysdummy1"
   alternateUsernameAllowed="true"
   validationQueryTimeout="10"
   validationInterval="30000"
   testWhileIdle="true"
   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
   />
</Context>
```

The reason for changing it to Tomcat connection pool is so that I can use this validationInterval property.  But the validationInterval still does not seem to be working.  In the log I see this warning below.  Is that means that the Tomcat Connection Pool setting is not taking effect?  Why is the factory property not supported?

```
INFO: Creating Resource(id=host-manager/jdbc/mcbell)
Nov 14, 2018 3:17:11 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler unusedProperty
WARNING: Property "factory" not supported by "host-manager/jdbc/mcbell"
```